# How to upgrade my AnkiDroid flashcards from 1.x to 2.0?

Tags: ankidroid

I am upgrading from AnkiDroid 1.x to AnkiDroid 2.0.

What is the upgrade procedure to make sure my flashcards and learning progress is not lost?

Comment: Copied from https://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/wiki/Upgrading because Google Code will become read-only and shut down soon.

Answer (score 1):

## How to upgrade to AnkiDroid 2.0

### Introduction

With the release of AnkiDroid 2.0, you need to upgrade your decks to the new (significantly improved) Anki 2 format. Besides upgrading your decks, you also need to upgrade to version 2.0 or later of Anki on your desktop if you use it. Anki2 brings a number of fundamental changes to the learning style which also affect AnkiDroid. Please take some time to read about them [here](http://ankisrs.net/docs/changes.html).

### Upgrading Decks

This guide is for Windows users; please allow 15-60 min to do this depending on your level of familiarity with Anki/AnkiDroid/PC.
If you are still having trouble after following this guide, post in the [forum](http://groups.google.com/group/anki-android) for personal assistance.

Please ensure that you have the [latest version](https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/releases/latest) of AnkiDroid installed!

#### Part A: Backup old AnkiDroid files to your PC

1. Connect your device to the PC with USB cable
2. Open windows explorer and click on your Android device
3. You should see a folder called "AnkiDroid" listed in your device
4. Copy this "AnkiDroid" folder to your Desktop
5. You should see all of your decks as DECKNAME.anki files. If not, go to the backup folder and copy and paste them into the AnkiDroid folder.

#### Part B: Upgrade old decks with Anki desktop software

1. Install the latest Anki desktop software from http://ankisrs.net
2. Open the Anki desktop software that you just installed
3. In this Anki desktop software go to file->import
4. Now navigate to to Desktop/AnkiDroid -> Change ("Files of type" > "Anki 1.2 Deck") -> Choose the first .anki deck
5. Do the same thing for each .anki deck in the AnkiDroid folder
6. Check that all of your decks are now listed in the main Anki software

#### Part C: Copy the upgraded decks back to your device

1. In Anki Desktop software go File->Export and click "Export" button
2. You should see a message saying a file called "collection.apgk" has been saved on your desktop
3. Go to your desktop and copy the "collection.apgk" file
4. Now open your mobile device again with windows explorer
5. Navigate to the AnkiDroid folder
6. Right click and paste the "collection.apgk" file
7. Now open AnkiDroid, open the menu and choose "Import cards" then click OK
   Now you should see all your decks there ready to start reviewing.

#### Part D: Move any media on your device to the "collection.media" folder

**This is not necessary if you don't use media**

1. In windows explorer open the AnkiDroid folder on your Android device again
2. Confirm that there is a folder called "collection.media" and some other folders that look like "deckname.media"
3. Open the first "deckname.media" folder
4. Select all files (press Ctrl+A on the keyboard)
5. Right click and Copy
6. Now go back and open the "collection.media" folder
7. Right click and paste
8. Wait for all the media files to finished moving
9. Repeat steps 4 to 8 for each of the other "deckname.media" folders
10. Confirm that all your media files are now in the "collection.media" folder
11. Optional: you can now delete the "deckname.media" folders if you like since these are not used in AnkiDroid2

**Note: This method can't handle different files with identical names.**

## More help

If you are still having problems with upgrading, please visit the main [Help](http://ankidroid.org/docs/help.html) page.